# After MYSQL query return if the row was updated or inserted

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-update, sql-insert

So I'm working on a part of my website where users can uprate and downrate content, this is stored one row per rating with a +1 for an upvote and a -1 for a downvote.

I also will be having a total of `upvote - downvotes` of the users profile page. The total of these votes will be stored in the mysql table of the users information.

My problem is that when someone votes something, lets say a downvote so I substract one to the total value of the votes on the users profile. But then if the user changes his mind and modifies the vote to an upvote well for the final value to be right I have to actually add 2 ( +1 to compensate the -1 and an other +1 for the upvote)

```
$sql = "    
    INSERT INTO `votes`
    (
        `added_by`, 
        `value`,
        `post_id`,
        `ip_created`
    )  VALUES (
        '".$logedInUser['User_ID']."',
        '".$value."',
        '".$this->post_id."',
        '".ip2()."'
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = '".$value."'
";
$db->sql_query($sql);
```

I know that I can figure out a way to do it, but it will require a few other queries and I'm hopping there is a way to be able to return if it was inserted or updated. (I know that the query will only return TRUE or FALSE)

Comment: before your query take the max key after the query take the max key and if they are different then you made an insert else it was an update

Comment: This is why you shouldn't denormalize your database.

Answer (score 1):

Do `select row_count();` right afterwards.

From MySQL documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

> For INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.

Here is an example.  It uses `mysql_affected_rows()` -- I know I know mysql_* is deprecated.

```
$mysql = mysql_connect(":/tmp/mysql.sock", "ckim", "");
mysql_select_db("test");
mysql_query("drop table if exists my_table");
mysql_query("create table my_table(id int primary key, val int)");

$result = mysql_query("insert into my_table values (1,1) on duplicate key update val = 2") or die (__FILE__.':'.__LINE__.": ".mysql_error(). "\n");
echo mysql_affected_rows()."\n";

$result = mysql_query("insert into my_table values (1,1) on duplicate key update val = 2") or die (__FILE__.':'.__LINE__.": ".mysql_error(). "\n");
echo mysql_affected_rows()."\n";

$result = mysql_query("insert into my_table values (2,1) on duplicate key update val = 2") or die (__FILE__.':'.__LINE__.": ".mysql_error(). "\n");
echo mysql_affected_rows()."\n";
mysql_close();
```

The output is

```
1
2
1
```

Comment: So, I tried this, I added this `$last = mysql_query("SELECT ROW_COUNT();");  $result = mysql_fetch_array($last); ` after my query but it always returns `0`. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Am I forgetting something ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I added an example for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current data structure, I think instead of the hack of adding 2 to balance the data when the user upvote and subtracting 2 when he downvotes again. Try this:

1. You have to first remove the vote.
2. Then cast another vote to make the change.